# Force Powerpoint Main window update

Tags: .net, winapi, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint AddIn in VSTO that do some operations like importing a slide from a template.

To be user-friendly, I open the template using WithWindow = MsoTriState.msoFalse

After the slide is inserted, the slide pane is not refreshed.

I have tried somes WinAPI calls like RedrawWindow but it doesnt works

How can I force an entire powerpoint's Window to refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

Call the presentation object's NewWindow method.  Here's a VBA example:

```
Sub ShowYourStuff()

    Dim oPres As Presentation
    Set oPres = Presentations.Add(msoFalse)
    oPres.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutChart
    oPres.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutFourObjects

    MsgBox "Ready to show the user stuff?"

    oPres.NewWindow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have used InvalidateRect to force PowerPoint to repaint the window but remember having difficulties if using it with a null rectangle.

You could try this

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure RECT
    Public left As Integer
    Public top As Integer
    Public right As Integer
    Public bottom As Integer
End Structure

...
Dim windowRect As RECT
GetWindowRect(New IntPtr(Application.HWND), windowRect)
InvalidateRect(New IntPtr(Application.HWND), New Rectangle(0, 0, windowRect.right - windowRect.left, windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top), True)
```